# regarding the generation of an automatic id

Tags: c#, sql

I want to generate an automatic ID in a textbox

The table in SQL goes like

```
Create table employee(empid varchar(50),empname varchar(50),sal int)
```

And the ID has to be in the format `TOO0`, `T001`, TOO2`, and so on.

Comment: show your code and more explanation also

Comment: You shouldn't. The ID should be generated SQL-side when the data is saved. Otherwise multiple users could "generate" the same ID (by entering in that page at the same time) or, on the opposite side, if an ID is created on the DB just because a user enters that page, then the user could simply exit without saving and many IDs would be wasted.

Answer (score 0):

1. Identify the components in your 'natural' key

   - Your key has a string prefix to an incrementing numeric value
2. Find the max numeric value for all existing values with the same prefix

   - This is the tricky and controversial bit, you will need to query the DB for all existing keys to... something like this can work in an SQL environment

...

```
SELECT 'TOO' + Cast(MAX(Right(EMPID, LEN(EMPID)-3) + 1) 
FROM   Employee  
WHERE  EMPID LIKE 'TOO%'
```

Ideally though you should do this inside a stored procedure or in the insert statement where you can minimise or remove the risk of multiple processes generating rows with the same key.

As a double check, make sure you add a unique index constraint to the EMPID key (if it is not already your primary key)

If you are hooked on displaying the emplid to the user before the row is created, then consider a model where you insert the row first to reserve the key and the user from here is just updating the blank entry. Of course now you will need to delete the row if they choose to cancel the operation.

> I am not entering into the argument of is this a good code pattern. To the coders out there who say 'Ids should only be generated in the DB' I agree but there are many valid scenarios where you may want to generate and use a 'natural' key.
>
> I strongly recommend the use of 'surrogate' (arbitrary key generated explicitly to identify the row) keys as the primary identifier of all rows of data in the DB, this simplifies the use of ORMs and other data factory tools.

Answer (score 0):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

```
    str = "select count(*) from employee";

    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);

    con.Open();

    count = Convert.ToInt16(com.ExecuteScalar()) + 1;

    txt_empid.Text = "E00" + count;

    con.Close();

}

protected void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HP-PC;Initial Catalog=kriti;Integrated Security=True");

    con.Open();

    str = "insert into employee values('" + txt_empid.Text.Trim() + "','" + txt_empname.Text.Trim() + "'," + txt_sal.Text.Trim() + ")";

    com = new SqlCommand(str, con);

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();

    con.Close();

    Label4.Text = "Records successfully Inserted";

}
```

This is my actual code and it is generating an error as unable to convert nvarchar value TOO1 to the data type int